# How to make auto login work in Ubuntu? (no display manager)

Tags: 15.04, ubuntu-minimal, auto-login

I am trying to autologin and auto startx on my ubuntu minimal installation
(15.04 Vivid Velvet 32bits, mini.iso)
I am following several guides that I found but none of them work (the startx part works, but not the autologin)

For example:
https://rowen121.wordpress.com/2011/09/14/enable-automatic-login-and-startx-in-ubuntu/
https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/autologin

One of the problems is everytime I go and look for the file they tell me to edit, it's not there.
When I do sudo nano whatever the file, it is empty (tty1.conf for example, or inittab)
In all the guides they say to uncomment a line and add another, but all those files are empty for me.
Maybe it is because they refer to Debian and things change.

I have managed to make it work installing nodm.
Then I don't need to write my username nor password, and then, it auto startx (I added startx in .bash_profile), and finally takes me to i3-wm. I haven't installed a display manager (well, just nodm as the last option to try) nor desktop environment.

I would like to get it working without the need of installing a display manager (rungetty/mingetty/getty/whatever works and it's easy on resources)
Please if you know the steps that work for you and ubuntu, or a guide that I can follow I would appreciate it.
Thanks in advance

Note: nothing is encrypted

Comment: So you're saying `/etc/init/tty1.conf` is empty for you ? that's weird . . . It's not a difference between Debian or Ubuntu. By default there *always* should be init files. And autologin is simple just alter the line `exec /sbin/getty   -8 38400 tty1` to `exec /sbin/getty -a username   -8 38400 tty1`

Comment: Yup, read that german wiki a little. The step is correct. Perhaps you are doing something wrong. Also , in `Automatischer Oberflächenstart nach Login` part I think it should be changed to `startx xfce4` not `startxfce4`, cuz that last command is non-existent

Comment: By minimal installation, I should have specified that I am in fact using ubuntu mini.iso (MinimalCD). Yes, I am sure tty.conf was empty, and inittab empty too.

Comment: Serg: I tried what you suggest but it doesn't work, I find myself in tty1 but I have to write my username and password. I re-tried the german wiki, but nothing. I have to write name and password

Comment: Ok. So another possibility is that Ubuntu uses different system to start processes as of 15.04 . Init files belong to Upstart system but 15.04 uses systemd. Try this https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Automatic_login_to_virtual_console

Comment: Ok, tried that but now it takes me to a black screen with blinking cursor, and I can't do anything.

Comment: This is what I did: sudo systemctl edit getty@tty1, then I added those three lines (changing username of course), and then CTRL+O (it said File Name to write: /etc/systemd/system/getty@tty1.service.d/.#override.confac3305a12536440b) I pressed on ENTER, and then CTRL+X. Then sudo reboot, and that's what happened.

Answer (score 7):

It seems you were right Serg, Ubuntu 15.04 now uses systemd, and apparently things have changed.
So I kept on searching now for systemd autologin and got it working.
I found this guide that served me well:
http://memo-linux.com/debian-8-systemd-autologin-sans-display-manager/

This is what I did:

```
sudo mkdir -pv /etc/systemd/system/getty@tty1.service.d/
sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/getty@tty1.service.d/autologin.conf
```

and edited the file as follows:

```
[Service]
ExecStart=
ExecStart=-/sbin/agetty --autologin username --noclear %I 38400 linux
```

Change "username" with yours.

Save and close (CTRL+O, CTRL+X)

Now:

```
systemctl enable getty@tty1.service
```

Write your password (I was asked twice)

That would be for the autologin part.
Next, to start X automatically, continue with this:

```
sudo nano ~/.bash_profile
```

and edit that file so it reads:

```
[[ -z $DISPLAY && $XDG_VTNR -eq 1 ]] && exec startx
```

Save and close (CTRL+O, CTRL+X)
(Source: wiki archlinux Autostart_X_at_login)

At this point I found another possibility for that file here:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/42359/how-can-i-autologin-to-desktop-with-systemd

```
if [[ -z $DISPLAY ]] && [[ $(tty) = /dev/tty1 ]]; then
 exec startx
fi
```

But I haven't tested it and I don't really know the difference, sorry.

In this last link they advised to do a last step
"You will have to modify your ~/.xinitrc to start your desktop environment, how to do that depends on the DE"
So I did:

```
sudo nano ~/.xinitrc
```

and added this line

```
exec i3
```

Save and close (CTRL+O, CTRL+X)

Last thing to do:

```
sudo reboot
```

Now it auto logins and auto starts X, and no display manager was needed.
I think I read if you already have a display manager you have to remove it first.
I hope this can be useful for you. Feel free to comment and improve it.

Comment: why is there `ExecStart` twice? I've tested it with only one `ExecStart` and it did not work. I'm curious

Comment: To tell you the truth, no idea. My answer was a compilation of the info I gathered when I was having this problem. I described what I tried and worked for me at the time. Maybe you can contact the creator of this blog here: [link](https://storma.wordpress.com/2012/11/28/debian-systemd-autologin-without-a-display-manager/)